# On computability of sheafification

Tags: computability-theory, sheaf-theory

The question will feature some imprecise words but I believe that an expert could parse it to a precise question more or less uniquely.

Assume I have a reasonable topological space (say the underlying space of a qcqs scheme). Assume I have a presheaf whose values on any open set are "algorithmically computable" (assume the same about restriction maps). Are the values of its sheafification over a given open set necessarily "algorithmically computable"? If not, maybe there are some non-tautological conditions on the presheaf that would guarantee it?

This question arose after I tried to compute the sheafification of some weird presheaves and found that to be no fun.